# Creating a bounding box to pull from cache

Tags: geoserver, cache

I have a simple python script that is pulling in lat,longs from company's db and we are trying to create several bounding boxes around these points to simulate zoom-levels. The script will pull tiles from the geoserver, but will not pull from cache. In the geoserver url, I have tiling enabled, but I have been told that the BB's I created do not line up with the "grid" for tiling, so it won't pull from geoservers cach? The documentation makes it seem like i should be able to pull from cache anyway.....any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand exactly what your question is, but if you are trying to create WMS requests for areas of interest (AOI) around your data points then using a WMS request with the boundingbox generated by the python sounds like the way to go.

If you want to make use of your tile cache (GWC) then you need a more sophisticated client which can take your generated bounding box and split it up into the required number of tile requests. Maybe something like http://nullege.com/codes/search/mapproxy.core.client.TMSClient would work for you.

Comment: If a database is involved, you could also create a [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29) that concatenates an appropriate `BBox` for each point---then the messy-looking stuff can be kept out of the code.